# How to implement Excel SUMIF criteria in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a VBA function to simulate an SQL SELECT query that fetch just one return value. The inputs to this function will be the table (range), values (array) and comparison operators (???). Example:

```
SQL(column_criteria As Array, table As Range, result_col As Integer)

' arr() takes variable number of values, stuff into an array and returns it    
SQL(arr("<= 35", "Male", ">= 120000"), Data!A1:H4, 4)
```

The SUMIF built-in function accepts in its criteria parameter a string value which seems quite versatile e.g. `> 5`, `Vegetables`, `*es` [according to Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx).

Is there some built-in way SUMIF use to parse the criteria string? Or do I have to hardcode with string comparison logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By parse the criteria string I'm assuming you mean multiple criteria?  In that case use SUMIFS for multiple criteria.

Making a few assumptions for example... summing data in A1:A6 based on criteria in B, C and D

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A6,B1:B6,"<=35",C1:C6,">=12000",D1:D6,"=Male")
```

Comment: Hmm... This suggestion is actually quite good if the criteria ranges guarantees unique selection and fetch only one row, but will not do well in other cases, for example, returning the first matched row.

Comment: Anyway, by parse I mean convert the string into code like... in PHP eval()... oh yes, EVALUATE()! Should have thought of it earlier!